# how to compile and run a cpp file using only one command in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

Recently I've started to learn cpp language on linux,and now I run a cpp file using following commands.

```
g++ -o xxx xxx.cpp
./xxx
```

Is there a way to make it one line command such as `compile-and-run xxx.cpp`?Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeremy Banks has posted [one of the most awesome tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830/most-elegant-amusing-or-strange-code-one-liners/12907#12907) I've seen in quite some time at SO. Basically, he's adding a single [Bash-Script line at the top of the cpp file](http://gist.github.com/448040), which allows him to directly compile and execute that file.

```
//&>/dev/null;x="${0%.*}";[ ! "$x" -ot "$0" ]||(rm -f "$x";cc -o "$x" "$0")&&exec "$x" "$@"
```

This explanation is copied from the gist:

> ```
> //
> ```
>
> Since we don't want this visible in C, we put it in a comment.
>
> ```
> &>/dev/null
> ```
>
> Unfortunately `//` is interpreted as an invalid shell command and
>   produces an error message, so we need to redirect that to `/dev/null`
>   to get rid of it.
>
> ```
> ;x="${0%.*}"
> ```
>
> This determines what our compiled filename will be by using string
>   replacement to get rid of any extensions on the current filename.
>
> ```
> ;[ ! "$x" -ot "$0" ]||
> ```
>
> This check if there already is a compiled version newer than the
>   source file. If not...
>
> ```
> (rm -f "$x";cc -o "$x" "$0")
> ```
>
> ...we delete any existing version and then compile our code, using our
>   chosen compiled filename.
>
> ```
> &&exec "$x" "$@"
> ```
>
> If the compile was successful or unnecessary, pass execution to the
>   compiled code, passing on the arguments given to this script.

This technique is called [a Polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29), which means that it is written in multiple languages and can also be interpreted by those language-interpreters without problems.

Comment: that's really a nice trick:)

Comment: the only problem is ,how to add this line to the head automatically everytime I create a cpp file~though this is another topic.

Comment: @SpawnST: How do you create this files? Most IDEs support adding automatic headers.

Comment: I like this. It is very tricky.

Comment: @Bodbby,i use vim.i'm going to make some hotkey for the code.

Answer (score 6):

What about this?
`g++ -o xxx xxx.cpp && ./xxx` ?
( `&&` means it'll wait until the first task is done, `&` means it'll start it right after it started the first, you do NOT want this one. )

Comment: I think Shiki understand well what '&' means in a unix shell, but just for those who are less informed, & means that the first command is run in background (but the output is directed still, to console unless redirection is used.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.it works fine.can it be more beautibul by do some alias stuff?I like the style `cplandrun xxx.cpp`..

Comment: @bubu yeah that's right, i got you:)

Comment: and for the matter, && means that the second command is run only after the first command is run correctly (i.e. return 'ok' to the command) -- if the command is run incorrectly, e.g. syntax error during compilation, '&& ./xxx' will not be run.

example:

ping -c 1 xxx.com > /dev/null && echo 'xxx.com up' || echo 'xxx.com down'

will ping xxx.com and show xxx.com up if the ping is successful, and show xxx.com down if it is not successful.

Comment: @SpawnST: An alias wouldn't do it, but as [lajuette](http://superuser.com/questions/156061/how-to-compile-and-run-a-cpp-file-using-only-one-command-in-linux/156069#156069) shows, a script will do it. Or it can be done in a function. Using **Shiki's** command: `crun () { g++ -o $1 $1.cpp && ./$1; }`. To use it: `crun xxx`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Makefile like this:

```
xxx: xxx.cpp
    g++ -o xxx xxx.cpp

run: xxx
   ./xxx
```

Then just type `make run`. Of course your Makefile can be much more elaborate than that, it's just a simple example. The important thing is the "run" clause.

Comment: that's even better than my idea to whip up a script.

Comment: Yes, good solution, and more clean than writing && always. :)

Answer (score 3):

a simple, generic makefile could do it:

```
$ cat Makefile  
.SUFFIXES: .o .c  

.c:   
        cc -o $@ $<  
        ./$@  
$ make myprogram
```

will compile myprogram.c and will run myprogram. As it is defined with default rules, this works for every .c file in this directory.

Naturally, you must care about libraries, include directories, and other dependencies ...

I hope this helps, nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

you can write a script. like:

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ -o $1 $1.cpp
./$1
```

then make it execupable `chmod u+x script.sh` and call it like `script.sh yourcode` 
(omit the cpp or alter the script).